# Export and Import Location

Tags: importexport, export, locations

Someone knows the location of the files important for Export and import?

Like for an example:

```
mywebsite/app/....
```

Because I want to repair it, because files are missing and I don't know where to put them.

Comment: you can see locations of import and export here : `mysite/var`

Comment: @BabyinMagento No, I mean where are the files which have the task to execute exports and imports